# Is mediating and thus becoming "awake" right before sleeping good?

Tags: meditation, mindfulness, meditation-effects, sleep, sati

Pretty much as the title suggests: does it harm to meditate before sleeping? For me if I meditate seriously my mind is swept over with awakeness. as a consequence when I go to sleep I remain awake for sometime and keep thinking useless thoughts. so it kind of hinders my sleep. Is there a good practice or should meditation before sleep be avoided?

Comment: Awakeness in meditation and normal awakeness (not sleeping) are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

The Buddha meditated before sleep however laying down on his right side. For example, two suttas say:

> "That is credible for the Master Gotama, as would be the case for one
> who is worthy & rightly self-awakened. But does the Master Gotama
> recall sleeping during the day?"
>
> "I recall, Aggivessana, in the last month of the hot season, after the
> meal, returning from my almsround, setting out my outer robe folded in
> four, lying down on my right side, and falling asleep while mindful &
> alert."
>
> [MN 36](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.036.than.html)

> “I’m not feeble that I lie down, nor am I drunk on poetry. Having
> reached the goal, I’m rid of sorrow. Alone in a secluded lodging, I
> lie down full of compassion for all living creatures.
>
> Even those with a dart stuck in the breast, piercing the heart again
> and again, are able to get some sleep. So why not I, whose dart is
> drawn out?
>
> I don’t lie awake tense, nor do I fear to sleep. The days and nights
> don’t disturb me, as I see no decline for myself in the world. That’s
> why I lie down full of compassion for all living creatures.”
>
> [SN 4.13](https://suttacentral.net/sn4.13/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=true&script=latin)

Comment: Did he sleep though? I am told by a teacher that he merely lied down but was completely awake during his "sleep". That made sense to be given Buddha was fully awakened

Answer (score 0):

Answer can be different according to the meditation type you do.

**Part 1)** : general answer

> Is mediating and thus becoming "awake" right before sleeping good?

Yes.
But only if one do actual meditation. Like Samatha(Kasina, Maithree), Vipassana.

It will not disturb your sleeping. But solidify the sleeping.

What does that mean?

When someone sleeps. His/her mind will do all sorts of stuff. Like dreaming the future, remembering past, dreaming imaginary situations. Which uses your energy (brain and other active parts). So body and mind doesn't get the full rest/relaxation of sleeping.

But if someone do meditation before sleep, his sleep will be more stable and more solid. (even you spend little time without reaching the sleep at the beginning).
Less dreams (fake). Less brain activity (my interpretation / could be incorrect) and less energy use.

So sleep will be just sleep. With less dreams, and you will feel very fresh when wake up.

> as a consequence when I go to sleep I remain awake for sometime and keep thinking useless thoughts.

This could happen if you do Kasina Bawana. I suggest you to do

- **Maithree Bawana** after doing your normal meditation procedure

Or

- **Maithree Bawana** after went to the bed (you can do while laying on the bed)
  .

**Part 2)** : references

**In Damma books / **Pali canon** it's clearly pointed out that good sleeping / sleep is a main direct result of Maithree Bawana.**
(There are 11 direct results you get when you do Maithree Bawana).

> Whether standing or walking, seated or lying down
> Free from drowsiness
> [Reference 1 / The Amaravati Sangha](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.1.08.amar.html)

As you can see in above reference, Buddha has clearly advices on doing Maithree meditation even when laying down on the bed. Buddha is saying, Maithree meditation is suitable for any human situation like, sitting, laying, while working.

[Reference 2 / Piyadassi Thera](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an11/an11.016.piya.html)

> 1. **He sleeps in comfort.** 2. **He awakes in comfort.** 3. **He sees no evil dreams.** 4. He is dear to human beings. 5. He is dear to non-human beings. 6. Devas (gods) protect him. 7. Fire, poison, and sword cannot touch him. 8. His mind can concentrate quickly. 9. His countenance is serene. 10. He dies without being confused in mind. 11. If he fails to attain arahantship (the highest sanctity) here and now, he will be reborn in the brahma-world.

[Reference 3 / Thanissaro Bhikkhu](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an11/an11.016.than.html)

[Reference 4 / www.dhammatalks.org](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/AN/AN11_16.html)

---

**Part 3)** : extra insight

Info :-

One can be awake in many ways. One can be normally awake, drunken awake(he/she is awake but has no real awareness, anesthesia, drug) , awake but without any awareness(like using high dose of anesthesia or drug).
In above situations, oneself is clearly awake(not sleeping, not in coma, not dead).

But when oneself do meditation, it's not the awakeness he/she get, but **awareness**. (some may call it awakeness).

**Meditation brings awakeness and awareness together and making mind more concentrated. (mostly Samatha meditation).**

**Thanks . ☸️.**

*Questions are welcome.*